# Can one wrap a systemd ExecStart in a shim without reiterating or changing the command line?

Tags: systemd

Let's say I have an existing systemd service:

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/whatever.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Dfoo=bar -Dbaz=qux -Xmeh=whatever -jar /path/to/whatever.jar arg1 arg2 ...
```

...and I want to use a drop-in to put it in a wrapper that runs the *exact same command*, but only after grabbing a lock first. The way I'm familiar with would be to clear the existing `ExecStart` and then reiterating it:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/whatever.service.d/needs-lock.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/with-lock lock-id /usr/bin/java -Dfoo=bar -Dbaz=qux -Xmeh=whatever -jar /path/to/whatever.jar arg1 arg2 ...
```

This is unfortunate: *I really just want to prepend `/usr/bin/with-lock lock-id` to the existing service*, without needing to modify my `needs-lock.conf` every time the upstream `whatever.service` definition changes.

Is there any reasonable way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, unfortunately there's no way to prepend to the existing service command-line... On the other hand, why would you need a lock? systemd should already prevent more than one instance of the service from starting...

Comment: @filbranden Think of cases where one has a cluster and needs to ensure that one and only one node successfully instantiates a service. That is to say, assume `with-lock` here is talking to zookeeper or consul or etcd.

Comment: Yes, I can see. But doing that as part of ExecStart might not be best (for example service is kept in "starting" state...) Look into [`ExecCondition=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecCondition=) as something that can help you check whether the cluster manager will allow this service to get started. Also `ExecStopPost=` is a possible hook to notify it this service went down. Anyways, consider whether this is really the right layer to implement cluster coordination, or if it belongs on a layer above this one.

Comment: I really do consider it the best layer. A parent process can continue to refresh a lock iif its subprocess is still running, and actively kill the child process should it be unable to do so -- so a node losing its power or otherwise suffering a hard failure no longer holds a lock as soon as the last lease times out, and a node losing its connection to the store managing the lock can be prevented from running the software without the lock held. You don't get that level of assurance if you're depending on ExecStop to successfully run.